# jQuery .prepend content has no height (ie. height:0px )

Tags: jquery, dom, prepend

my code:

```
$( ".panel article:first-child" ).prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

loaded in body. i see `<p>Test</p>` in the html in the correct place, but rendered with no height.

any help? thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the surrounding elements, the CSS applied to all of this, a working example, *something* that might give a clue as to the cause? No idea.

Comment: Basically, from the information you've provided, your problem is [no-repro](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/986uwmqu/).

Comment: yes.. trying to see how i can shed light

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see its height then you need to prepend it with a certain `height` value like this:

```
  $( ".panel article:first-child" ).prepend( "<p style='height:20px'>Test</p>" );
```

Comment: @vulgarbulgar set a higher value for height

Comment: Why do you think you need to explicitly assign a height to the element?

Comment: likely wrong, but because it currently has a height of 0

Answer (score 0):

as @david-thomas mentioned, no-repro. the issue was the element i was targeting was rendered after the .prepend. i tested with another target, and worked as expected. sorry for the crappy question.

cheers.